# BSD-3 Closed Source Attribution

Tags: licensing, bsd, closed-source

I'm having some confusion with the BSD-3 license language.  I am going to close source a bsd-3 project and make modifications to it.  I will not be redistributing the code.  It will be used as a SaaS.  Users will pay to use the updated software and for support, but will never get the actual source code.

If attribution is required, where do I put it?  I know the codebase has the license already in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only attribution required by BSD is to maintain the copyright/license statement within your sources, but if you aren't distributing the code you don't even need to do that (although you should, in case years from now you or your heirs want to transfer the software to someone else).

As @Philipe Ombredanne pointed out, redistributions of BSD-3 licensed software in binary form must reproduce the copyright notice, license and disclaimer in the documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.  This would not apply if you aren't resdistributing the software.  If you distribute documentation, it would be good to include this information in it, but you would not be required to.  But before omitting the licensing information, check with your own lawyer.

Comment: Actually in the case of a three clause BSD, the copyright and license should be reproduced in the "documention and/or other material..." https://enterprise.dejacode.com/license_library/Demo/bsd-new/#license-text